# Phalcon custom assets routing within Module

Tags: php, phalcon

Using [Phalcon Assets Management](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/assets.html). I'm able to add assets like JS, CSS file into volt template from the controller.

But the assets manager will always looks inside "public" folder for assets.

How can we access "assets" folder which is inside "module" directory?

So that each module will have there own assets defined.

Here's my current folder structure:

```
---apps
------module_1
---------controllers
---------models
---------views
------------assets // how to access this to get JS, CSS, Img files into Volt Template?
---public
------assets // currently all assets are accessed by this folder by default
```

Answer (score 2):

The Assets Manager is just a like [View Helper](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tags.html) to your code be more future proof.

I think you're trying to apply the MVC pattern on the server and client side at once, and [**that's not going to work**](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2013/03/23/client-side-mvc/). I mean, the server/client side segregation comes first than MVC itself.

I admit that the MVC Pattern gets a bit confusing on the client-side of a Web Application, but that's another history. Simply remain with everything that's **isn't processed by the server** in your public folder and you'll be fine. You can even create one folder for each module like you wanted in the 'public/assets' path.